# When running a program from within a program using system() in stdlib.h, how do I simulate typing to feed the sub-program's scanf call?

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a program to run a different program over and over, giving it different input to a question each time, checking the output.  `system("the_program")` accomplishes this, but how do I give that program input when it runs `scanf()`?

Comment: I believe `fork()` and another `system('input')` call will do this. Confidence rating not high enough to post as answer though..!

Comment: It has been done - see http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to write a file, and pass it to the child using redirection (`system("the_program < the_file")`).

But, and this is much better, you can make a pipe between your program and the child. The child needs to have its standard input (file descriptor 0) connected to the reading side of the pipe. `system` is synchronous, so besides `pipe` and `dup2` you need the `fork` and `execve` system calls. Luckily, there is a wrapper for this process: `popen("the_program", "w")`. It returns a FILE* that you can write to. Close the FILE* with `pclose`, and be sure to read the manual because it is different from fclose!

Comment: EDIT: after reading, it seems that popen only allows one-way motion; I need two-way so I can compare the output to my input.  I will thus have to do the pipes and forks and whatnot myself.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

**In the case where you are writing *both* parent and child programs**, there is no need to a solve a problem arising by simulating something else, when we can just pass in arguments:

`system('./the_program the_scanf_input')`

And of course the_program:

```
var = argv[1] //this was var = scanf('%', &var)
```

Comment: Because I do not have access to the child's source, so I can't modify it to accept the input as an argument.  It demands scanf.

Comment: Oh, my apologies - I thought you were writing both.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect.